# How find and free glScene objects....?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, glscene

i wrote this code to dynamic create led

```
var
  fLed: Tglhudsprite;
  i,fImgSnapNum: integer;
  ............
for i := 0 to fImgSnapNum - 1 do
  begin
    fLed := TGLHUDSprite.CreateAsChild(MainForm.Dummy_Sound);
    fLed.Name := 'fLed' + IntToStr(i);
    fled.Material.MaterialLibrary := MatLib;
    fLed.Material.LibMaterialName := 'led';
    fLed.Width := fLed.Material.GetActualPrimaryTexture.Image.Width;
    fLed.Height := fLed.Material.GetActualPrimaryTexture.Image.Height;
    fled.SetSize(18,18);
    fled.Position.X := 530 + (i * 30);
    fled.Position.Y := 600;
    fled.Visible := true;
end;
```

how can i find and free the fLed glscene objects... ?

Thank you...
I use delphi7 and GLScene components...

Comment: Can't you just call Free on them?

Comment: Rob no i can't. When i free with fled.free and run again the creation of dynamic led then i get an error that "component "fled0" already exists"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious way to free the objects is simply to call their `Free` method, the same as you'd free any other object. The code shown creates many objects, so you need to have some way of freeing all of them; only the single most recently created object will still be in the `fled` variable. The naïve solution to that is simply to keep a list of those objects in some container, such as [`TObjectList`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Contnrs.TObjectList). Then iterate over the container and free its contents.

You might not need a separate container, though. The owner argument you pass to the sprites' constructor maintains a list of all the things it owns. You can iterate over its [`Components`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TComponent.Components) array, just like you can with any other descendant of `TComponent`.

Finally, since you're assigning the `Name` properties of all the objects, you can call [`Dummy_Sound.FindComponent`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TComponent.FindComponent) to find each sprite component by its name. (And if you're *not* searching for such dynamically allocated components by name, then there's little reason to assign the `Name` property in the first place.)

Comment: Thank you rob ... my mistake is to call the glscene not the dummycube... so nothing returns ... you free my mind...Thank you